# XSLT Sorting with first letter of family name

Tags: xslt, sorting, xslt-1.0

I am trying to modify the following xsl so that the output matches the desired output shown below. I am trying to sort the records alphabetically by the first name of the family Initial. However at the moment it only sorts by the creators initial I need it to include the editors initial where the record does not have a creators element.

XML:

```
 <records>
  <record>
    <creators>
      <item>
        <name>
          <family>Smith</family>
          <given>Tim</given>
        </name>
      </item>
    </creators>
   </record>
  <record>
    <creators>
      <item>
        <name>
          <family>Lambert</family>
          <given>John</given>
        </name>
      </item>
    </creators>
    <editors>
      <item>
        <name>
          <family>testEDITOR</family>
          <given>Bob</given>
        </name>
      </item>
    </editors>
  </record>
 <record>
   <editors>
      <item>
        <name>
          <family>ZambertEDITOR</family>
          <given>Bob</given>
        </name>
      </item>
    </editors>
   </record>
```

XSL:

```
 <xsl:key name="initial" match="record" use="substring(creators/item/name/family,1,1)"/> 

<xsl:template match="/"> 
<xsl:for-each select="//record[generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('initial', substring(creators/item/name/family,1,1))[1])]"> 
    <xsl:sort select="substring(creators/item/name/family,1,1)"/> 
    <xsl:for-each select="key('initial', substring(creators/item/name/family,1,1))"> 
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1"> 
                   <br /><h3 class="border"> 
                   <xsl:value-of select="substring(creators/item/name/family,1,1)"/> 
          </h3> 
        </xsl:if> 
        <p>
                  <xsl:value-of select="creators/item/name/family"/> 
        </p>        
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

Desired output:

```
L
Lambert

S
Smith

Z
ZambertEDITOR
```

Comment: If the case of both `creators` and `editors` matters for your problem then I strongly suggest to show us an input sample where that is the case. And please explain whether the order of those two elements is known when both can be present.

Comment: The provided XML document isn't quite representative. Please, edit the question and add a `record`, that has both `creators` and `editors` children. Also, you are witholding an important fact that you want the sort to be done only on the first letter of `family` -- please explain this clearly in the question.

Comment: Thanks, have made these changes and updated the question.

Comment: @user598241 if you want to notify them, @ their names, or they will never know you changed something. read the *help* next to this comment box.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks, have made these changes and updated the question.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, Thanks, have made these changes and updated the question.

Comment: @user598241, Seems you are missing one of the editors from the wanted output. Please, edit and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a simple grouping problem**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kWith1stLetter" match="family" use="substring(.,1,1)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
  "*/*/*/*/family
             [generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('kWith1stLetter',substring(.,1,1))[1])
             ]">
    <xsl:sort select="substring(.,1,1)" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match= "family">
    <h3 class="border">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,1)"/>
    </h3>

    <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup"
          select="key('kWith1stLetter',substring(.,1,1))"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="family" mode="inGroup">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<records>
    <record>
        <creators>
            <item>
                <name>
                    <family>Smith</family>
                    <given>Tim</given>
                </name>
            </item>
        </creators>
    </record>
    <record>
        <creators>
            <item>
                <name>
                    <family>Lambert</family>
                    <given>John</given>
                </name>
            </item>
        </creators>
        <editors>
            <item>
                <name>
                    <family>testEDITOR</family>
                    <given>Bob</given>
                </name>
            </item>
        </editors>
    </record>
    <record>
        <editors>
            <item>
                <name>
                    <family>ZambertEDITOR</family>
                    <given>Bob</given>
                </name>
            </item>
        </editors>
    </record>
</records>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<h3 class="border">L</h3>
<p>Lambert</p>
<h3 class="border">S</h3>
<p>Smith</p>
<h3 class="border">t</h3>
<p>testEDITOR</p>
<h3 class="border">Z</h3>
<p>ZambertEDITOR</p>
```

**and it is displayed by the browser as:**

L

Lambert

S

Smith

t

testEDITOR

Z

ZambertEDITOR

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian  Grouping Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.